# How to enable BtSnoop logs in Android Comms Test Suite

Tags: bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am new to Android Comms Test Suite. Working on Bluetooth technology.
My query is that how to enable btsnoop so that it can be collected automatically through ACTS.

Is there some configuration(.config/.json) to enable in ACTS so that it will collect BtSnoop logs automatically.

I have searched the internet but not able to find right solution.